# $watch behaviour depending on promise value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-promise, watch

I have a function that is called at the initialization of a controller that calls a `$http.get` service (promise). This promise retrieves a list of items from a webservice. I also have a `$watch` on the properties of the list pagination.

My problem is that what I do in the `$watch` depends on the promise (and the `$watch` isn't watching it, the list is only loaded once). So when loading the page, the webservice is called, then the `$watch` (before the list is initialized), and then I get the return of my promise. So what happens in the $watch isn't the right behaviour.

Is there a way to make the `$watch` wait on the promise return ?

Comment: put the `$watch` expression in the `.then` or `.done`(whichever you're using). your question is too abstract. maybe i'd be able to help if i could see the code.

Comment: you could have a watch inside `function` and call that function  when your promise completed, so that it would get register.

Comment: Well that worked, sorry for the pretty dumb question, I don't know why I didn't try that before. Thank you both

Answer (score 0):

It is better to post some code to get correct answer.

I suggest you should use `$watchCollection` on paging object, or `$watch` with third parameter `objectEquality = true`.

To update list loaded from your web service you should not use `$watch` on promise object, you should use `.than()` method of promise.